# Why doesn't the JQuery `attr()` method work for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 `var setOpenModal = function () {
    var theControl = $('.fOpenModal');
     theControl.off().on('click', function () {`if (WorkStates == 'To be PO') {
        $('#fPO').prop('checked', true);
        $("#fVendorCB1").attr('style', 'display:none');

     }else if(WorkStates == 'To be RFQ'){
        $('#fRFQ').prop('checked', true);
        $("#fVendorRad1").attr('style', 'display:none');
     }
        $.ajax({
                url:blalala',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                 blalala,
                }
            })
        .done(function (json) {
            $.each(json.rows, function (index, data) {
             htmlPart += "<td>";
             htmlPart += "<input type='radio' id='fVendorRad1'  name='VendorRad'  value=" + data.ID + " " + isPO + ">";
             htmlPart += "<input type='checkbox' id='fVendorCB1' name='VendorCB'  value=" + data.ID + " " + isRFQ + " >" + data.Name + "<span class='ref-num'>" + "(" + data.ID + ")" + "</span>";
             htmlPart += "</td>";
    }
};
```

I want to add attribute 'style = display:none'  through JQuery to tag HTML '`$("#fVendorRad1").attr('style', 'display:none');`' and  `$("#fVendorCB1").attr('style', 'display:none');` but it is not working.

The data html there are  in the same object

Comment: It's `.css("display", "none")` (what you have works fine btw, but it will overwrite any other inline style)

Comment: Instead of `attr()` you can use `css('display','none')`

Comment: Are `fVendorRad1` and `fVendorCB1` the inputs you add to htmlPart? Or are these already in the DOM and htmlPart will just replace the original elements? Since you cannot select elements with $() before they are actually on the page. So if the former is true, you have to add the styling and selected attributes in the input string, not select them from the DOM, since they aren't rendered yet.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to use `attr()` for this, when `hide()` is available. Also, how is the second code block related to the first? Is that added to the DOM before you execute your `if` conditions? If not, there's your problem.

Comment: Also note that what you have already works: https://jsfiddle.net/64dhekot/. If it's not working for you please edit the question to include a more accurate example of your JS/HTML and also check the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your help but it diffrent context..i will update the code for a minute

Answer (score 0):

Two things use `===` instead of `==` and use [css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) function to add inline style

```
if (WorkStates === 'To be PO') {
  $('#fPO').prop('checked', true);
  $("#fVendorCB1").css('display', 'none');

} else if (WorkStates === 'To be RFQ') {
  $('#fRFQ').prop('checked', true);
  $("#fVendorRad1").css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but still not working

Comment: @ImmanuelSaragih please share your full relevant code

Comment: Technically the OPs code already works: https://jsfiddle.net/64dhekot/. Therefore there must be some other underlying issue.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.hide()` method to hide elements

Comment: is not working too

Comment: @ImmanuelSaragih then you need to update your question to make the context of your code much clearer as what you have is already working: https://jsfiddle.net/64dhekot/.

Comment: If this answer is "wrong" then all the others need to be deleted as well, as they all provide the same solution to OP's already working code.

Answer (score -1):

The `.attr()` method is used for setting or getting the value of a certain attribute.

**Example:**

```
<img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" />
```

```js
$("img").attr("src") // - This would return 'images/logo.png'
```

In order to style your element you have to use the `.css()` method:

```js
$("img").css("display", "none"); // - This will hide your element
```

It can also be used to apply multiple styles like this:

```js
$("img").css({
    "display": "none",
    "border": "1px solid #000"
});
```

Read more about the `.css()` method [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp).

Read more about the `.attr()` method [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp).